# direction : rtl doesn't work with angular material cards?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm using angular material cards and want to make text start from right to left , so i used direction: rtl; but it wasn't work .
any help ? 
HTML Code :

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
   <mat-card-header>
     <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>
         <button class="profilrButton" (click)="viewProfile(post.uid)">{{post.fullName}}</button>
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
          <p wrapper>{{post.title}} </p>
        </mat-card-subtitle>
      <mat-card-subtitle style="float: right;font-size: 8pt">{{arr[ind]['date']}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>

  <img mat-card-image src={{post.imageURL}} alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  <mat-card-content>
     <p [class]="(hasArabic(post.description))? 'pre rtl':'pre'">
       {{post.description}}
     </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
     <button class="classA" (click)="approve(post.key,ind)" mat-button>Accept</button>
     <button class="classR" (click)="delete(post.key,ind)" mat-button>Reject</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

CSS

```
.pre{
 white-space: pre-line;
}
.rtl{
 direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Material uses the `dir` attribute more than the `direction` style.  Try:

```
  <mat-card-content>
     <p [dir]="(hasArabic(post.description)) ? 'rtl' : 'auto'" class="pre">
       {{post.description}}
     </p>
  </mat-card-content>
```

You may also want to read up on the [bidirectionality module](https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview) but I think that is more for your own custom components that are used by Material components.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Angular Material components does not know about the change in css and it relies on the Directionality service from @angular/cdk/bidi to know about direction changes.

```
import { Directionality } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';

constructor(private dir: Directionality) { }

changeLanguageToRTL() {
  document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
  
  // Notify Material components of the change
  (this.dir as any).value = 'rtl';
```